# SyntaxError: missing ) after formal parameters

Tags: javascript, function, var

I run into the same error over and over again within the debugger, "SyntaxError: missing ) after formal parameters".

Here are my parameters I set:

```
var CircleOptions = {
    posBall: {
        x: 160, 
        y: 180
    },
    radius: 40,
    startAngle: 0, 
    endAngle: Math.PI * 2, 
    anticlockwise: false,
    radians: 0,
    xMove: Math.random(),
    yMove: Math.random(),
    speed:2,
    angle:80,
    velocityX:1,
    velocityY:1
};
```

This is my code:

```
function CircleCoordinates(CircleOptions.posBall.x, CircleOptions.posBall.y, CircleOptions.radius) {
    var left = CircleOptions.posBall.x - CircleOptions.radius,
    top = CircleOptions.posBall.y + CircleOptions.radius,
    right = CircleOptions.posBall.x + CircleOptions.radius,
    bottom = CircleOptions.posBall.y - CircleOptions.radius;
};
```

I get the same error as well when I enter my functions as well:

```
function CircleCoordinates(CircleOptions.posBall.x, CircleOptions.posBall.y, CircleOptions.radius) {
    var left = CircleOptions.posBall.x - CircleOptions.radius;
    var top = CircleOptions.posBall.y + CircleOptions.radius;
    var right = CircleOptions.posBall.x + CircleOptions.radius;
    var bottom = CircleOptions.posBall.y - CircleOptions.radius;
};
```

Can anyone be so kind as to tell me what is wrong? :)

Comment: A parameter cannot be called `CircleOptions.posBall.x`, that's not a valid variable name.

Comment: This is invalid JavaScript syntax. Those are not valid argument names.

Comment: Where is `CircleOptions` defined/assigned values?

Comment: These are the parameters I set before hand: var CircleOptions = {
   posBall: {
    x: 160, 
             y: 180
            },
    radius: 40,
    startAngle: 0, 
    endAngle: Math.PI * 2, 
    anticlockwise: false,
    radians: 0,
      xMove: Math.random(),
      yMove: Math.random(),
      speed:2,
      angle:80,
      velocityX:1,
      velocityY:1
     };

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
function CircleCoordinates(CircleOptions) {
    var left = CircleOptions.posBall.x - CircleOptions.radius,
    top = CircleOptions.posBall.y + CircleOptions.radius,
    right = CircleOptions.posBall.x + CircleOptions.radius,
    bottom = CircleOptions.posBall.y - CircleOptions.radius;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
function CircleCoordinates(x, y, radius) {
    var left = x - radius,
    top = y + radius,
    right = x + radius,
    bottom = y - radius;
};
```

I think that's what you want.

Comment: I think Marko's is the better answer, as OP defines and is trying to use `CircleOptions`.

Comment: oh oops, totally skipped over the `CircleOptions` object

Answer (score 0):

Another reason that this error can occur is if you had a temporary mental lapse, and tried to declare types for your function parameters as though you were working in a C-style typed language such as Java or C#!

For example, this (incorrect syntax) JavaScript function declaration will produce  `SyntaxError: missing ) after formal parameters`:

```
function CircleCoordinates(int x, int y, double radius) {
    // ...
};
```

You need to omit the type declarations:

```
function CircleCoordinates(x, y, radius) {
    // ...
};
```